# Passing function to other if in same page

Tags: php

I have somthing like thet (i using each if for validate forms with AJAX)

E.G:

```
 if($proc=="x"){

             ...some other proccses codes

             list($bol,$file) = returnImgBolean();
                 if($bol == true){
                  var_dump($file);
                  }

 }elseif($proc == "y"){

         ...some other proccses codes

        function returnImgBolean(){
            if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)){
                     return array(true,$_FILES[$fileElementName]);
            }else{
                     @unlink($_FILES[$fileElementName]);    
                     return false;
            }
       }


 }
```

But it wont working , i get : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function returnImgBolean()` 
how i transfer the function to other if in the same page?

EDIT 1:
I tryed to pull out the function but now i get other error:

```
function returnImgBolean($msg,$file){
        if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)){
        return array(true,$file);
        }else{
        @unlink($_FILES[$fileElementName]); 
        return false;
        }
    }

if($proc=="x"){

             ...some other proccses codes

             list($bol,$file) = returnImgBolean($msg,$file);
                 if($bol == true){
                  var_dump($file);
                  }

 }elseif($proc == "y"){

         ...some other proccses codes

  returnImgBolean($msg,$_FILES[$fileElementName]);


 }
```

Now the error is :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: msg
```

Answer (score 3):

When you first call `returnImgBolean()` it is out of scope. move it out of the elseif block like this:

```
function returnImgBolean() {
     if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)) {
         return array(true,$_FILES[$fileElementName]);
     } else {
         @unlink($_FILES[$fileElementName]);    
         return false;
     }
}

if($proc=="x"){

    ...some other proccses codes

    list($bol,$file) = returnImgBolean();
    if( $bol == true ) {
         var_dump($file);
    }
 } elseif( $proc == "y" ) {

         ...some other proccses codes

 }
```

Comment: Ok,i got idea from u to make it working i will test and edit.

Comment: where are you declaring / getting $msg from?

Comment: Yea , this the problem , i declaring it in the same if , i testing now somthing and will edit if work or not. -EDIT: Its not working ERROR: Undefined $msg . look my edit.

Comment: you are passing $msg to the to the function `list($bol,$file) = returnImgBolean($msg,$file);` where is this coming from?

Comment: Look my edit ,from top of the page , behind the IF'S , i call the function once with the params inside send them to the function in top and try to pull out the parms in the other if but not working even with ur example..

Comment: $msg is not initialised at this point `list($bol,$file) = returnImgBolean($msg,$file);`